# Laravel not showing result in custom page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have 2 pages. One page called "user" it's a user profile page. And another has called "stats" it's a user profile stats page.
I included in "user" profile "stats" page like that:

```
@if (request()->is('*/stats'))
@include('users::show') 
@endif
```

Cuz I have the "stats" link on the user page.

So i want to display something in stats and user profile page like that:

```
{{ floor($user->matchesWonPercentage) }}%
```

On the "stats" page this is working normally. But on the profile page, I get always 0.

My controller:

```
public function show($slug) {
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    if (! $user->isActivated()) {
        $this->alertInfo(trans('app.access_denied'));
        return;
    }       
    $user->access_counter++;
    $user->save();
    $this->pageView('users::show', compact('user'));
}

public function stats($slug) {
    /** @var User $user *
    $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    if (! $user->isActivated()) {
        $this->alertInfo(trans('app.access_denied'));
        return;
    }
    if ($user->mix_played) {
        $user->matchesWonPercentage = 100 * $user->games_won / $user->games_played;
    } else {
        $user->matchesWonPercentage = '0';
        $this->pageView('users::stats', compact('user'));
    }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing not good? I'm new on Laravel so don't be mad on my :) Thanks!

Comment: i think you just not set up the object data 'matchesWonPercentage' for profile page